# java runtime redirect c program output

Tags: java, c, bash, exec, io-redirection

I have a problem redirect a c program to java runtime class. It's a similar problem like

[Java Runtime execute C language program get no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520997/java-runtime-execute-c-language-program-get-no-output)

However, the answer doesn't help me, and I am guessing because I am in windows environment. I have installed Cygwin and add the path C:\cygwin64\bin to my environment to run my c program. My C program is below and compiled as a.exe:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

In my java program:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\a.exe");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while (in.ready()) {
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
    }
```

This code prints nothing. However, If I changed

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\a.exe");

to other bash commands like

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -la");

It works!

I have tried use ProcessBuilder to redirect the output, running "a.exe" doesn't work but "ls -la" works. This is the code:

```
File output = new File("C:\\outputfile.txt"); 
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\a.exe").inheritIO();
pb.redirectOutput(output);
Process p = pb.start();
```

My guesses are something related Cgywin but I have no idea how to fix this. Does anyone know what's wrong? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I have spent all day doing this research, and finally I fix this by restarting my computer..... and everything works....